# Visual Studio Community - .Net 7 Docker Compose not debugging

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose, .net-7.0

I'm developing two apis in .Net 7, which for now are just two projects with the same code provided for .Net 7 Web Api template.

If I run each project using the docker profile I'm able to debug and everything else.

As soon I added docker container orchestrator support, and tried to run, nothing happens.

It doesn't show any logs in the container, it doesn't bound any ports.

Any ideas what could be happening?

```bash
docker exec -i c2c765869778 /bin/sh -c "if PID=$(pidof dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
Error: No such container: c2c765869778
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/SnakeGame.Server.Application.ManagerApi_1_1$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
bff43b096bee
docker exec -i bff43b096bee /bin/sh -c "if PID=$(pidof dotnet); then kill $PID; fi"
Error: No such container: bff43b096bee
========== Debugging ==========
docker ps --filter "status=running" --filter "label=com.docker.compose.service" --filter "name=^/SnakeGame.Server.Application.ManagerApi_1_1$" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
d8562d7aeb12
```

[image: Docker Desktop]

[image: Docker Desktop Inspect]

[image: Docker Desktop Logs]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I enabled 
`Place solution and project in the same directory` 
while creating a new ASP.NET web api project.
When this is disabled, it worked.